# Import CSV file of locations into Android once, not every runtime

Tags: android, google-maps, csv

I am trying to import a csv file into an android app. The file is a list of about 2000 locations, given by name, address, telephone number, state and postcode. I then need to find the closest of these to the user, and show the location and map.

I can import the locations when the app starts by parsing the csv file, but I was wondering if there is any way to permanently import the locations, so the csv file does not need to be parsed everytime a user opens the app? I have been looking into KML files, but while that will load locations, it does not seem to be able to sort by distance very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a background service. When your app does the initial onCreate, you can start the service processing the CSV. As long as your app is still in memory, you should be fine.

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Alternatively, you could create a service component. This would run somewhat independently of your app. The service component can open the CSV file and live longer than the app. So, even if the app is killed, the service remains running.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Yeah that is what i am leaning toward at the moment, I just figured there should be a way to hard code the locations into the app, but if not this seems like the best bet

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from making a big array of CSV values in your app. It's not pretty or a good coding practice by any means, but it certainly would be hard coded at that point.